# How do I load a csv file in neo4j v4.1.3

Tags: csv, neo4j

I have code
LOAD CSV FROM `file:///DepartmentsHeadless.csv` AS row
WITH toInteger(row[2]) AS DeptChair, row[1] AS DeptName, (row[0]) AS DeptPrefix
RETURN DeptPrefix, DeptName, DeptChair

and have tried surrounding the  file:///.....csv with backticks, single quotes and double quotes and get the message that "couldn't load the external resource at file:/C:/..... with correct path all the way to the file which is in my import folder.
Sometimes (with back ticks) I get: Variable `file:///DepartmentsHeadless.csv` not defined (line 1, column 15 (offset: 14))
"LOAD CSV FROM `file:///DepartmentsHeadless.csv` AS row"

Answer (score 0):

In short, neo4j looks in the /import folder for files (security reasons), and by default does not allow any other paths, more on that [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/load-csv/)

Note: it would be helpful if you add information about how you are running neo4j (from neo4j desktop client?), and where you are running the load csv command (desktop client or browser?)

Comment: I am running the Neo4j Desktop v 4.1 under Windows 10.  The csv files were put in the import folder, and I tried to load them using the Neo4j Browser.  THX